# Android and Facebook with FB App installed

Tags: android, facebook

I'm getting grays with Facebook API and FB App installed on the phone.

I perform check if FB is installed, just to log it, and I get the following:

```
10-23 12:08:35.193: W/FAcebook(21888): PackageInfo{41908a68 com.facebook.katana}
```

(So, Facebook found) and then when I try to perform login / photo upload:

```
10-23 12:08:40.208: E/ActivityThread(21888): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
```

In my app, if FB app is not installed, it all works fine. If FB is on the device it self, it does not work, but I do not get (any more) the message that App is miss-configured.

I get only that small error in Log, and when I try to perform action from my app, the FB app appears for couple of seconds with spinner "working", then it disappears and that's it.

Does not crash, does not log me in, does not give any info...

Comment: Are you using v3 of the Facebook SDK for Android?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the 3.0 version.

Comment: Sorry - one other question, what version of the Facebook app itself do you have installed?

Comment: Hi James, well It's Facebook 1.9.6 installed. I've changed the code in the mean time using sessions in proper way, so I do not have issue with this any more. But this problem remains for apps designed for old API.